# Add a leading zero to integer column

Tags: r, string, dataframe

Sorry for the basic question, but I cannot figure out how to change a string of characters and numbers.
I have a dataframe *datafile* with a column *subject* with 28 different numbers/subject (4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, etc.). I need to change these numbers into strings like 'sbj04', 'sbj05', 'sbj08', 'sbj09','sbj10', 'sbj11','sbj12', etc.
I've tried different things, but they don't work.

```
datafile$subject = as.factor(datafile$subject) #it works
datafile$subject <- sub("^", "sbj", datafile$subject ) #it works, but all numbers become 'sbj4', 'sbj5', 'sbj8', 'sbj9', sbj10', etc.
```

the following code doesn't return what I need

```
datafile[datafile$subject == "sbj4"] <- "sbj04"
datafile[datafile$subject == "sbj5"] <- "sbj05"
datafile[datafile$subject == "sbj8"] <- "sbj08"
datafile[datafile$subject == "sbj9"] <- "sbj09"
```

the following code doesn't return what I need

```
datafile[datafile$subject == "sbj4",] <- datafile[datafile$subject == "sbj04",]
datafile[datafile$subject == "sbj5",] <- datafile[datafile$subject == "sbj05",]
datafile[datafile$subject == "sbj8",] <- datafile[datafile$subject == "sbj08",]
datafile[datafile$subject == "sbj9",] <- datafile[datafile$subject == "sbj09",]
```

the following code doesn't return what I need

```
if (datafile$subject < 10) {
      datafile$subject <- sub("^", "sbj0", datafile$subject )
    } else{
      datafile$subject <- sub("^", "sbj", datafile$subject )
    }
```

Comment: In your description you say you have just integers while in your code your actual values aren't.

Comment: @DavidArenburg, because when I run the code `datafile$subject <- sub("^", "sbj", datafile$subject )` they become 'sbj4', 'sbj5', etc..

Comment: Try `paste0("sbj", stringi::stri_pad_left(1:12, 2, 0))`. You can replace `1:12` with your original `subject` column. Or just `sprintf("%02d", 1:12)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way to do this if you actually have numeric values is to use `sprintf` (in base R).

Example:

```
> x <- 1:15
> sprintf("sbj%02.f", x)
 [1] "sbj01" "sbj02" "sbj03" "sbj04" "sbj05" "sbj06" "sbj07" "sbj08" "sbj09"
[10] "sbj10" "sbj11" "sbj12" "sbj13" "sbj14" "sbj15"
```

Thus, you should try something like:

```
datafile$subject <- sprintf("sbj%02.f", datafile$subject)
```